# Get the most current datetime of 2 similar records and only display the most current

Tags: sql, t-sql

Any help would be appreciated. Here's my issue...
I have a table that have similar records but different update times. e.g -

```
ID          ComputerName    DomainName  OSType       LastUpdate
12345   PC1111          WORK        Windows7         Mar  5 2014 10:24PM
1723    PC1111          WORK        Windows7         Mar 15 2014  8:30PM
23455       PC1111          WORK        Windows7         Mar 17 2014  8:44PM
```

The pc names are the same but I can use the IDs and LastUpdate to return just the newest LastUpdate time. I tried MAX(LastUpdate) but no good. I tried TOP 1 and still no good. I am still very new to T-SQL and this is kicking my arse!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a cte with `row_number`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELLECT ID, ComputerName, DomainName, OSType, LastUpdate,
       rn = row_number() over (partition by ComputerName order by LastUpdate desc)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT ID, ComputerName, DomainName, OSType, LastUpdate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Tim you really helped me out here. This worked very well for what I needed. Thanks for the quick intro to CTEs. I guess the same Ranking can be used to get the total number of rows returned. I will try to figure that one out. Again, thank you!

Comment: If you mean the total number of rows per `ComputerName`, yes, then you can also use a ranking function: `PcCount=COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ComputerName)`. If you mean the total count use simply `Total=(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM dbo.TableName)`.

Comment: Thanks again Tim. I did figure out how to get the count. Time to read up on Ranking. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 (
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ComputerName ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC) AS RN
 FROM Table_NAME
 )Q
WHERE rn = 1
```

With this query the returned result set will have an extra column `RN`. just select the column you want by using the column names explicitly in your select statement.

To learn more about the RANKING functions read here [`SQL SERVER RANKING FUNCTIONS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I used Tim's query above to get the job done, but yours also works well. Thanks for the link to the SQL Server Ranking material. I will use that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As a join:

"Find a computer update for which we can find no other update of a computer with the same name and a update time that lies beyond my update"

```
SELECT    c1.*
FROM      computers c1
LEFT JOIN computers c2
ON        c1.name = c2.name
AND       c1.lastUpdate > c2.lastUpdate
WHERE     c2.id IS NULL
```

or with a correlated subquery:

"Get the computer update that has the maximum update time of all other updates of computers with the same name."

```
SELECT    c1.*
FROM      computers c1
WHERE     c1.lastUpdate = (
             SELECT max(c2.lastUpdate)
             FROM   computers c2
             WHERE  c2.name = c1.name
          )
```

Comment: Roland just a question is this method more efficient than using sql server's ranking functions ?

Comment: You'd have to try. I provided these queries as complement. The windowing functions and CTE's are great tools but these queries show you how you could do it without them. If you're stuck with MySQL, you end up with queries like these. At any rate these queries would benefit from an index over (name, lastupdate). In fact these queries assume the combination of name and lastupdate is unique, if not, the first query will return nothing and the second query could return duplicate rows

Comment: I did'nt mean to criticise at all I was just wondering if you have had any experience of comparing performance of these good old joins and ranking function. will test it someday :)

Comment: Hi M.Ali! Hey, it's ok - I didn't take your question as criticism. I'm sorry if my answer suggests I did. By "you'd have to try" I merely meant that you should compare the different solutions to see what suits you best. It's just that performance depends on not just the query but a lot of other things, including which version of the RDBMS, the size of the dataset, the indexes, your server configuration, etc etc. If I knew, I'd've said it :)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the data type of the column! If LastUpdate is declared as a datetime\smalldatetime etc ordering and selecting the top 1 should work. If it declared as some sort of string then it will do a sort based on the string value which is probably what you are getting.

try

```
select Max(convert(datetime, LastUpdate, 103))
from Table
```

or

```
select Top 1 LastUpdate
from Table
order by convert(datetime, date, 103) ASC
```

The above two examples convert your string into a date data type. This will mean that SQL Server will know how to sort it when you ask it to!